# Accessing object inside array that is inside another object using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter-3

I am new to CI. Using codeigniter, I am trying to print categories and their items as below:

**Category 1 Name**

1. item 1
2. item 2

**Category 2 Name**

3. item 3
4. item 4
5. item 5

and so on.
I have build an array and subarray inside controller as below:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->publicpages_model->getcategories();
foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
{
    $data['categories'][$category->cID]= $this->publicpages_model->getitems($category->cID);
}
```

In the view, I am trying to use the following code but I am not able to complete it to get the desired output as discussed above.

```
foreach($categories AS $category)
{
    echo '<h1>' . $category->name . '</h1>';

    //Missing code to print the items

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Although the name of category is printed but I am also getting the following error:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

print_r($categories) gives following result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cID] => 1 [name] => Breakfast ) [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [itemID] => 1 [name] => Aaloo Paratha [description] => descriptio 1 [menu] => 1 [price] => 22 [tax] => 20 [sStatus] => ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [cID] => 7 [name] => Fast Food ) [5] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [itemID] => 5 [name] => Missi Roti [description] => Hot and Crunchy [menu] => 5 [price] => 5 [tax] => 1 [sStatus] => 1 ) ) [7] => )
```

vardump gives following output:

```
array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (2) { ["cID"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "Breakfast" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (7) { ["itemID"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(13) "Aaloo Paratha" ["description"]=> string(12) "descriptio 1" ["menu"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(2) "22" ["tax"]=> string(2) "20" ["sStatus"]=> string(0) "" } } [2]=> object(stdClass)#24 (2) { ["cID"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(9) "Fast Food" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (7) { ["itemID"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(10) "Missi Roti" ["description"]=> string(15) "Hot and Crunchy" ["menu"]=> string(1) "5" ["price"]=> string(1) "5" ["tax"]=> string(1) "1" ["sStatus"]=> string(1) "1" } } [7]=> bool(false) }
```

Please help with the solution.

Comment: Can you please dump the result of the $this->publicpages_model->getitems($category->cID); and add in the question so that we can help you better

Comment: post complete error message and post data arrays as well

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari I have updated the dumps in question detail

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have updated the dumps in question detail

Comment: Check your foreach, there is something wrong. You was change `$data['categories']` as a category. But you still call in the foreach using `$data['categories']`

Answer (score 1):

You have a little problem there in your code. What you are trying to do is fine, but how you do it is the problem.

In this foreach loop, you are modifying the same array which you loop; hence it breaks the structure of the `$data['categories']` array completely. As a result of that, your second element of the array is not having a `name` key, so it throws that warning.

```
foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
{
    $data['categories'][$category->cID] = ...;
}
```

If you were trying to get the subitems of each category, and add them as a new key, you need to modify the `$category` array. Not the outer array :) So change it like this.

```
foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
{
    $category->subItems = $this->publicpages_model->getitems($category->cID);
}
```

Or if you wanted the `$category->cID` instead of the key `subItems`, you can change the above to this:

```
foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
{
    $category->{$category->cID} = $this->publicpages_model->getitems($category->cID);
}
```

I hope it helps :) feel free to ask anything if it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

imho what you are doing makes no sense - you should add the items to the category

try the following instead

**your controller**

```
$data['categories'] = $this->publicpages_model->getcategories();
foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
{
    $category->arrItems = $this->publicpages_model->getitems($category->cID);
}
```

**your view**

```
foreach($categories AS $category)
{
    echo '<h1>' . $category->name . '</h1>';

    if (isset($category->arrItems) && is_array($category->arrItems))
    {
        foreach($category->arrItems AS $objItem)
        {
            print_r($objItem);
        }
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```